# RESTful does not post into database.

Tags: javascript, html, rest

I am trying to integrate my HTML and RESTful services in Javascript. Before I changed the code, it was working, but now it doesn't work. If I hardcode values my code does work, but when I get them from DOM it does not.

For example, here is the Javascript part:

```
function loadXMLDocAddUser()
{
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/insertuser/" + $('#SigningUp').find('input[name = "userName"]').val() + "&" + $('#SigningUp').find('input[name = "password"]').val()+ "&" + "male" + "&" + "photo"
    })
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
}
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

The query string shouldn't be in the URL field when using $.ajax(). Instead, put it in the data field.

```
function loadXMLDocAddUser()
{
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/insertuser/",
      data: $('#SigningUp').find('input[name = "userName"]').val() + "&" + $('#SigningUp').find('input[name = "password"]').val()+ "&" + "male" + "&" + "photo"
    })
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
}
```

Comment: It is not that. For example, this one works:var password = $("#newpassword").val();
var username = $("#newusernameee").val();
var gander = $("#newgender").val();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/insertuser/"+username+"&"+password+"&"+gander+"&photourl"
  
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
}